# How to make background image blur on link hover?

Tags: html, css, blur

I'd like to make my background image blur for let's say 5px when you hover the link with a mouse cursor. Is there any simple way to make this happen?
I got a bit entangled with classes and id's here...

```css
#pic {
  background: url(http://www.metalinjection.net/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/space-metal.jpg);
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 500px;
  /*blur using this function*/
  filter: blur(0);
  -webkit-filter: blur(0);
  -moz-filter: blur(0);
  -o-filter: blur(0);
  -ms-filter: blur(0);
}

.banner_link {
  font-family: 'Raleway';
  letter-spacing: 0.2em;
  font-size: 13px;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 16px;
  padding-top: 45px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.banner_link a:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
  height: 1px;
  width: 90px;
  background: #ffffff;
  transition: width .2s ease, background-color .5s ease;
}

.banner_link a:hover:after {
  width: 0px;
  background: transparent;
}

.banner_link a:hover #pic {
  filter: blur(5px);
  -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
  -moz-filter: blur(5px);
  -o-filter: blur(5px);
  -ms-filter: blur(5px);
}
```

```html
<div id="pic" class="banner">
  <div class="banner_link"><a>Link</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This issue is that you are attempting to traverse *up* the document tree with CSS. There is no parent selector in CSS, therefore you can only rely on JS to toggle the blur effect when the inner `<a>` element is hovered on.

This can be easily achieved using native JS, but I've chosen to use jQuery because of the relative ease of use.

The trick is quite simple: to absolutely position a blurred version of the background image, nested in a pseudo-element, say `::before`, with its opacity set to zero. When the cursor is over the inner `<a>` element, toggle a class, say `.blur`, which sets the pseudo-element's opacity to 1.

The reason why we can't use JS to set the CSS properties of the pseudo-element is because it is not accessible to JS.

```js
$(function() {
  $('.banner_link a').hover(function() {
    $('#pic').addClass('blur');
  }, function() {
    $('#pic').removeClass('blur');
  });
});
```

```css
#pic {
  background: url(http://www.metalinjection.net/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/space-metal.jpg);
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 500px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#pic::before {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  display: block;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: url(http://www.metalinjection.net/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/space-metal.jpg);
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
  filter: blur(5px);
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity .5s ease-in-out;
}
#pic.blur::before {
  opacity: 1;
}
.banner_link {
  font-family: 'Raleway';
  letter-spacing: 0.2em;
  font-size: 13px;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 16px;
  padding-top: 45px;
  position: relative;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.banner_link a::after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
  height: 1px;
  width: 90px;
  background: #ffffff;
  transition: width .2s ease, background-color .5s ease;
}

.banner_link a:hover:after {
  width: 0px;
  background: transparent;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="pic" class="banner">
  <div class="banner_link"><a>Link</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Looks really nice thank you, but I can't get it to work. I'm using parallax .js as well, and the background image is not possitioned at 0,0,0,0 is it possible that this prevents content from working?

Comment: If I understand correctly it's background layered on top of the original background, am I right?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. If you're using another plugin to emulate a parallax effect, then the solution is not that simple — would be nice if you mentioned it in your question.

Comment: I see, yes I apologise I haven't. Still I'll make good use for this anyway, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
#pic a:hover  {  
    background: url(<-- insert blurred image here -->);
}`
```

This is the easiest way to create the effect you are looking for. As I'm sure you know, the issue is one of scope. You cannot (to my knowledge) set the background of a parent element from a child element without a JS workaround.

Answer (score 0):

**Implementation in jQuery**

This is the working one. When you hover the link it will make the image blur via jQuery.

See the jsfiddle link below

```
http://jsfiddle.net/ahmukovf/
```

Code

```
$( ".banner_link" ).hover(function() {
  $('#pic').css("-webkit-filter", "blur(3px)", "filter", "blur(3px)");
});
$( ".banner_link" ).mouseout(function() {
  $('#pic').css("-webkit-filter", "blur(0px)", "filter", "blur(0px)");
});
```

**Implementation in CSS**

See this working jsfiddle if you want to achieve it via CSS.

```
http://jsfiddle.net/9jqax4jb/
```

Code

```
.banner_link a:hover + #pic {
  filter: blur(5px);
  -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
  -moz-filter: blur(5px);
  -o-filter: blur(5px);
  -ms-filter: blur(5px);
}
```

Comment: It's worth noting that you're introducing jQuery when there's no implication that he's using any sort of JS library.  Not saying there's a better answer, just saying that it's worth noting...

Comment: He did not specify how he want to implementing it. So, it can be via jQuery or CSS. Although i think its more better if he can see in different way how to solve the problem.

Comment: I agree that JS is the way to go for this problem, but IMO, it's poor practice to utilize an entire framework to solve one relatively simple issue that could be addressed with pure JS.  Not only that, but you didn't make mention that you were using jQuery, which is kind of an important detail.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I also edited my post and add the implementation via CSS

Comment: Applying a simple CSS property? [There's a framework for that](http://www.needsmorejquery.com/).