# mouse hover of image to blur the image and display text

Tags: css, mouseover, blur

i would like to have a page with 4 sections of different background image. On mouse hover, it should blur the image and show a text. on click it should redirect to different html file. please help!

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#div1").hover(function(){
$(this).css("opacity", "0.5");
});
});
</script>
<title>Background Image in Quadrants</title>
<style type="text/css">
.tl { position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; right: 50%; bottom: 50%; 
      background: url(pic1.jpg) no-repeat;background-size: 100% 100%;     border:solid #000; border-width: 0 10px 10px 0; }
.t2 { position: absolute; top: 0; left: 50%; right: 0; bottom: 50%; 
      background: url(pic1.jpg) no-repeat;background-size: 100% 100%;     border:solid #000; border-width: 0 0 10px 0; }
.t3 { position: absolute; top: 50%; left: 0; right: 50%; bottom: 0; 
      background: url(pic1.jpg) no-repeat;background-size: 100% 100%;     border:solid #000; border-width: 0 10px 0 0; }
.t4 { position: absolute; top: 50%; left: 50%; right: 0; bottom: 0; 
      background: url(pic1.jpg) no-repeat;background-size: 100% 100%;     border:solid #000; border-width: 0 0 10px 0; } 
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="div1" class="tl"></div>
<div id="div2" class="t2"></div>
<div id="div3" class="t3"></div>
<div id="div4" class="t4"></div>
</body>
 </html>
```

Comment: Have you looked at https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/f/filter/

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29707562/how-to-make-background-image-blur-on-link-hover

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.
http://jsfiddle.net/zdtmnpk2/1/

```css
.tl { position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; right: 50%; bottom: 50%; 
      background: url(http://assets.servedby-buysellads.com/p/manage/asset/id/15119) no-repeat;background-size: 100% 100%;     border:solid #000; border-width: 0 10px 10px 0; }
.t2 { position: absolute; top: 0; left: 50%; right: 0; bottom: 50%; 
      background: url(http://assets.servedby-buysellads.com/p/manage/asset/id/15119) no-repeat;background-size: 100% 100%;     border:solid #000; border-width: 0 0 10px 0; }
.t3 { position: absolute; top: 50%; left: 0; right: 50%; bottom: 0; 
      background: url(http://assets.servedby-buysellads.com/p/manage/asset/id/15119) no-repeat;background-size: 100% 100%;     border:solid #000; border-width: 0 10px 0 0; }
.t4 { position: absolute; top: 50%; left: 50%; right: 0; bottom: 0; 
      background: url(http://assets.servedby-buysellads.com/p/manage/asset/id/15119) no-repeat;background-size: 100% 100%;     border:solid #000; border-width: 0 0 10px 0; } 


.tl:hover, .t2:hover, .t3:hover, .t4:hover{ -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
  -moz-filter: blur(5px);
  -o-filter: blur(5px);
  -ms-filter: blur(5px);
  filter: blur(5px);
}

span{
    color: #fff; 
    position: absolute;
    display:none;
    z-index: 5;
    
}
.text:hover > span { display:block; }
```

```html
<div class="text">
    <div id="div1" class="tl"></div>
    <span>Some text</span>
</div>
<div class="text">
    <div id="div2" class="t2"></div>
</div>
<div class="text">
    <div id="div3" class="t3"></div>
</div>
<div class="text">
    <div id="div4" class="t4"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I believe the `-ms-` and `-o-` rules there are non existing... `-moz-` possibly as well.